# How do I export InlineDrawing as an image in Document?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an InlineDrawing in my document, which I can access as an element, and get it as "InlineDrawing".. I also know how to access an InlineImage and write it to a file as bytes. How would I export an InlineDrawing as an image of some kind, the formats available from the UI are svg, pdf, jpeg and png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps script cannot do such image conversions for now... You could ask for an enhancement on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that I'd need to request but wanted to check here before posting for an enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the paragraph into a new document. Then you can convert the new document to pdf. Something like this:

```
var temporaryFileName = Math.random().toString(36);
var doc = DocumentApp.create(temporaryFileName);
// Child is the element with the InlineDrawing.
var originalParagraph = child.getParent().copy();
doc.getBody().appendParagraph(originalParagraph);
doc.saveAndClose();
// Save image.
var blob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
blob.setName("bla.pdf");
folder.createFile(blob);
```