# Google script InlineDrawing class

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to insert InlineDrawing into table cell.

According to documentation you can add InlineDrawing to Paragraph.

so

```
tr = table.appendTableRow();

var tc1 = tr.appendTableCell();

var tc1.appendParagraph( how to fit new InlineDrawing here? );
```

How to get new instance of inlineDrawing ? How to work with this object ? 
I can't find any online reference about this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: (credit: https://gist.github.com/bennettscience/cd51762de17c860d6930)

```
// Don't forget your global variables up top.
// Search through the page elements. Paragraphs are top-level, which is why I start with those.
if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){

  // Look for child elements within the paragraph. Inline Drawings are children.
  if(element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() !=0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING) {

    // For whatever reason, drawings don't have their own methods in the InlineDrawing class. This bit copies and adds it to the bottom of the doc.
    var drawing = element.asParagraph().copy();
    body.appendParagraph(drawing);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've also noticed Google's documentation is lacking in many areas. You have to use the copy() method to get a copy of it. See an example code snippet here: [How do I export InlineDrawing as an image in Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736068/how-do-i-export-inlinedrawing-as-an-image-in-document). In that, he uses `child.getParent().copy()` to get the paragraph with the InlineDrawing. There's only one other reference I found (http://googlestyle.client.jp/document_services/class_inlinedrawing.html). See the `removeFromParent` section, where he uses `getImages` to get a list of handles to images in the document.

Comment: So I should call 

var tc1.appendParagraph( InlineDrawing.copy());

or use something like ? 

var tc1.appendParagraph( paragraph.asInlineDrawing() );

Comment: please try out for yourself and report back with what you've tried, errors, etc.

Comment: I've tried 

`var drawing = InlineDrawing();` // err: InlineDrawing is not defined
`var drawing = new InlineDrawing();` // err: InlineDrawing is not defined
 `body.appendInlineDrawing();` // function doesnt exists
`tc1.appendParagraph(new InlineDrawing());` //InlineDrawing not defined 

I'm really helpless. I can't make even basic InlineDrawing "hello World"...

Comment: I don't think you can create your own inline drawing from the script API. you can only copy an existing one. So what you're trying doesn't make sense. Go thru the example I gave you. You need to get the inline drawing already existing in some paragraph like in the example and then make a copy into your table.

Comment: Oh, I thought that it is possible to create new InlineDrawing and then edit it. Its shame google can't do that. 
Thank you for your effort and help.