# Google Apps Scripts - Copy Inline Drawing from One Document to Another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to copy an entire document from one to another.

I am simply trying to copy an INLINE_DRAWING from one google doc to another but I keep getting this error. If I remove the attempt to append the drawing then there is no errors, but then in my finished document there are no drawings. How do you properly copy inline drawings from one doc to another?

```
// fromFile & toFile are objects after calling .getBody()
function copyFileContentsFromTo(fromFile,toFile){

    for(var i=0; i<fromFile.getNumChildren();i++){ //run through the elements of the template doc's Body.
      var child = fromFile.getChild(i);
      switch (fromFile.getChild(i).getType()) { //Deal with the various types of Elements we will encounter and append.
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
          // Look for child elements within the paragraph. Inline Drawings are children.
          if(child.asParagraph().getNumChildren() !=0 && child.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING) {
            console.log("Found an Inline Drawing");
            var drawing = child.asParagraph();
            toFile.append(drawing.copy()); // This causes the error!
          }else{
            toFile.appendParagraph(child.copy());
          }
          break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
          toFile.appendTable(child.copy());
          break;
        default:
          console.log("Whoops. Did not handle this Element Type when Copy Data from Template to Main: " + fromFile.getChild(i).getType());
          break;
      }
    }
}
```

I have already search all over and cant find any resources, this is the closest but still yields the error in my screenshot: [Google script InlineDrawing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983060/google-script-inlinedrawing-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, it is required to modify as follows.

#### From:

```
toFile.append(drawing.copy());
```

#### To:

```
toFile.appendParagraph(drawing.copy());
```

#### IMPORTANT:

- In the current stage, when the paragraph including the inline drawings is copied, please disable V8 runtime. When the above-modified script is used with V8 runtime, an error like `Exception: Action not allowed` occurs. So please be careful about this. This has already been reported at Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161999487) I would ilke to believe this bug can be removed in the future update.

#### Reference:

- [appendParagraph(paragraph)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphparagraph)

Comment: oh my...I did not know the V8 runtime was causing that issue. If I disable does that mean I need to convert all my code away from using javascript Classes and other syntax? Any other workaround?

Comment: @Sliffcak Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `If I disable does that mean I need to convert all my code away from using javascript Classes and other syntax?`, it's yes. I deeply apologize for this. If you want to run only the function `copyFileContentsFromTo` without V8 runtime, as a workaround, how about executing the function by Web Apps? By this, you can use your current script with V8 runtime by separating the function `copyFileContentsFromTo`.

Comment: okay I see. For now I will just convert the syntax of my codebase. I was not aware of the V8 bug with inline drawings. Marking as resolved. Thank you again!

Comment: @Sliffcak Thank you for replying. I would like to expect that this bug will be resolved in the future update. So in the current stage, as a simple way, I think that the script without using V8 runtime might be simpler than the workaround using Web Apps.